# WPF app doesn't shut down because of invisible main window instance

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, window

Some mysterious things are happening to my WPF app. I changed main window and after closing it app doesn't shut down. Here's my App.xaml:

```
    <Application
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LogAnalysis" x:Class="LogAnalysis.App"
         StartupUri="ChartWindow.xaml" ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
        <Application.MainWindow>
            <local:ChartWindow/>
        </Application.MainWindow>
    </Application>
```

I tried to figure out why process is still alive after closing and wrote this:

```
    foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((window as Window).Title);
    }
```

Two message boxes with the same message were shown.
So, it seem like there are two instances of main window are running in the one instance of app.

I can't use solution with this:

```
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

because `Window.Closing` event is triggered twice because of the second instance of the window (and it corrupts user settings).

Comment: Can you at least put log into your MainWindow's constructor and log the CallStack ? Should be  able to tell you which is the caller of generating extra window (if there's any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, finally got it. In the App.xaml file there is no need to determine Main Window property explicity. So, this code is not only redundant, it also calls window constructor:

```
    <Application.MainWindow>
        <local:ChartWindow/>
    </Application.MainWindow>
```

It will be enough to change only `StartupUri` property.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is an exact answer to your question, because I have no way of knowing why there are two MainWindow instances, but you could move the saving of your user settings to the `Application.ApplicationExit` (WinForms) or `Application.Current.Exit` (WPF) method, which will only get called once, after calling `Shutdown()`.

Comment: thanks, but did you mean `Application.Current.Exit`? Is it the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that is the WPF method, my mistake. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Tried to do as you suggested and nothig actually changed. I call `Shutdown()` in my `Window.Closing` handler, it triggers `Application.Current.Exit` event for the first time and closes my invisible window so `Window.Closing` is triggered again and process repeats.(